# Xcode path resources in Cordova structure

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

how can I change in Xcode this line

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:(@"%@",[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]) ofType:@"pdf"];
```

to look in Phonegap (cordova) file structure for the PDF like:

```
 ~/Library/Caches
```

or

```
~/Docuemnts
```

Comment: I believe the answer lies somewhere in [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). I have not yet used it, but it looks like you would be looking for the following paths:

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer for you, but I believe the [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) plugin is where the answer will be found. I have only limited experience with it, but it looks like you would be looking for the following paths:

- `cordova.file.cacheDirectory = '~/Library/Caches'`
- `cordova.file.documentsDirectory = '~/Documents'`

From the cordova documentation, it looks like you'll be trying to get a [`DirectoryEntry`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry) from the window object, and then use a [`DirectoryReader`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader) to iterate over the contained files. There may be a search, but I don't know the API well enough beyond the basics.

```
var bundleDocs = window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory);

var bundleDocsReader = bundleDocs.createReader();

bundleDocsReader.readEntries(
    function success(files) { // iterate over files and do stuff }, 
    function error(err) { // respond to error }
);
```

Hope that helps!

*NOTE*: The direct API references for DirectoryEntry and DirectoryReader link to the Cordova 3.0 documentation because the Cordova 5.1 documentation for plugins is awful.